# unrecognized Sierra 5570/8805

Tags: drivers, dell, xfce

I have a problem. I know you have heard it many times. I have a tablet Dell Venue 11 5130 with wwan/wi-fi card Sierra 8805 but in the system it is 5570e. I have needed for my work some easy-carry computer with 3G or lte. That is why i bought that one. I was able to install ubuntu (15.10 with xfce for lightness) in it, found touch keyboard for log in (it is great). One thing have not been working and it is the wwan card - sierra 68FDP9. I was trying to find something on the internet but i was unable to find any working solution (or did I miss something?).

I tried `lspci -nnk` but the card was not there at all.

There were:

1. Host bridge
2. VGA compatible controller
3. USB controller
4. Encryption controller
5. ISA bridge

The card is for a pcie or a M.2 slot

Some of the solutions (for sierra card but not for the type i have) was for ubuntu 9.10 and that is really old i have though.

For example, I tried solution from [this internet page](https://sigquit.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/dell-branded-sierra-wireless-3g4g-modem-not-online/). However when I wrote:

```
sudo qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --dms-get-operating-mode
```

the answer was:

> Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected error: couldn't create client for the "dms" service: CID allocation failed in the CTL client: Transaction timed out

Does it mean that my tablet have used "mbim" type of standard instead of "qmi" or is there a mistake somewhere?

Could someone help to make it work?

Comment: Hi guys, you are very helpful with no help!

Answer (score 0):

LTE modems are attached to an USB bus. Use lsusb to see it, or preferably "lsusb -v" to see all details.

It is most likely configured for MBIM mode by default.  Use ModemManager and let it drive the modem in that mode, unless you have good reasons to do things differently.